# How do I to filter a subform in Access? What is the control name?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to filter a table with a form and I'm having trouble with the macro.

My form is similar to this one and field1 is first name, field2 is city, and field3 is birth year.
[image: Link to Picture one]

I want to run this query on the subform or something similar so it filters the subform based on the combo box parameters.
[image: Link to picture Two]

My issue is with the control name I can't seem to come up with anything that works.
[image: Link to Picture Three]

Thank You! Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: were you trying to add images? You need to edit your post and ensure you are adding some code we can look at.

Comment: Doesn't really need to be form/subform arrangement. A single form can be used. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. Note the use of VBA instead macro. I don't use macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some testing. The Control Name is the name of the subform container control. In this case it will be the container name only, no `Forms!Form1` prefix. Recommend you name the container control different from the object it holds, such as ctrDetails. It works if the container holds a table, query, form, or report.

[image]

Comment: where am I able to find the sub form container control

Comment: the section is a selection type in the property sheet

Comment: I've named the label control and I've tried just control, forms!form1!control, forms!form1.form.controls!control and a number of other things I'm still lost. The section was just the part of the form that you put everything in

Answer (score 0):

New here - so couldn't comment or vote on answer above. Using the name of the container worked for me!  The container is essentially the yellow subform border when you highlight the subform. The container name is found in property sheet > other > name. And it was searchable in the Control Name box when building the macro.

Property Sheet:

[image: Property Sheet]

Macro:

[image: Macro]